# Why does a percentage width in the top li collapse the children li's?

Tags: css

I can't figure out why If I change the top li in a menu from px's to a percentage the child menu items stop displaying normally and fall over each other.

JS fiddle working:
http://jsfiddle.net/mg6vx/

JSfiddle not working (added width:20%; to #nav li):
http://jsfiddle.net/4eyp5/

HTML:

```
<div id="nav">
<ul>
<li><a href="#" title="About Us">About Us</a>
<ul>
<li><a href="#" title="stuff">Ab</a></li>
<li><a href="#" title="stuff">out</a></li>
<li><a href="#" title="stuff">Us</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li><a href="#" title="stuff">Stuff</a>
<ul>
<li><a href="#" title="stuff">Stuffed</a></li>
<li><a href="#" title="stuff">stuffs</a></li>
<li><a href="#" title="stuff">Stuffeds</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li><a href="#" title="Some Such">Some Such</a>
<ul>
<li><a href="#" title="stuff">Doohickey</a></li>
<li><a href="#" title="stuff">Widgets</a></li>
<li><a href="#" title="stuff">Things that amazon sells for one star</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li><a href="#" title="Careers">Careers</a>
<ul>
<li><a href="#" title="stuff">Interal postings</a></li>
<li><a href="#" title="stuff">External postings</a></li>
<li><a href="#" title="stuff">Theoretical postings</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#nav * {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    }

#nav li {
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    list-style:none;
    background-color:black;
    /* if you add this the child li's fall over themselves width:20%; */
    }

#nav li a {
    width:100px;
    height:30px;
    display:block;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align:center;
    line-height:25px;
    color: white;
    }

#nav li a:hover {
    background-color: #009;
    text-decoration: underline;
    }

#nav ul ul {
    position: absolute;
    top: 30px;
    visibility: hidden;
    }

#nav ul li:hover ul {
    visibility:visible;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @fizzix points out, each `li` has a width of `20%` of the parent. The nested `li` elements therefore have a small width because they are `20%` of `20%`.. etc.

You should use the [child combinator, `>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#child-combinators), in order to prevent styling from effecting nested `li` elements.

Something like this would work: [**(example)**](http://jsfiddle.net/LTw9x/)

```
#nav > ul > li {
    width:20%;
}
#nav > ul > li > ul,
#nav > ul > li > ul > li,
#nav ul li a {
    width:100%;
}
```

Comment: Ah I think I see what you mean. since my CSS isn't specific enough each li is 20% of its parent, so the child li's are 20% or the top level 20%. Am I right in thinking this is the problem?

Comment: @user2093601 Yep, that's the problem. You could use the child combinator to sort that out. Take a look at the example. Is that what you are aiming for?

Comment: Yes that works wonderfully. If you were to make a css menu responsive is that how you would write it or did I start my html css menu incorrectly to begin with?

Comment: @user2093601 The HTML looks good. I don't think you should have trouble making it responsive, it's just a matter of changing it from a horizontal to a vertical navigation.

Answer (score 1):

It is because you are giving them a specific width (being 20%), therefore it allows the list items to fit next to each other. In easier terms, you have 100% to work with and you are giving every list item 20%. Hence, you could then fit 5 list items on the same line.

If you can explain a little more on what you are trying to achieve exactly, we can help you find an alternative approach.

Comment: Im simply trying to make a css menu list that has responsive width (I'll add @media queries later for smaller screens). I chose 20% just as a test to see if the top level li's would adjust to screen size. They do but as you can see the child li's cover each other up now.